# Wordpress does not send email confirmation to newly registered users

Tags: login, email

This issue came to my notice when i saw new users trying to reset their password, when I asked them why they're doing this, they told me no email was sent to them after registering on site. My WordPress is recently updated and is hosted on a Centos dedicated machine.

Comment: It could be a WP issue, but it also could be a server issue as well as a user issue. I would try some troubleshooting first... for example, create a new user yourself, and see if you get the e-mail, if not, check your server to see if the e-mail was sent, then check spam box, and so on...

Comment: It could also be spf and dkim issues.  If your ip is different than that of the emails, it will not send them to gmail or outlook.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have a wrong server configuration. You can try some SMTP plugins like [WP Mail SMTP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/), configure and test your mailbox with this plugin.

Comment: Don't think this is the issue since as far as I understand from the question they did receive the reset email just not the new user email. @WalterMitty can you confirm this ?